# How do I mask a custom UI Graphic in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graphics, mask, unity-components

In Unity 2017, I've managed to draw vector graphics by making my own UI behaviors that inherit from `UnityEngine.UI.Graphic`. But my code is irrelevant because you can observe this problem just as well using the [SimpleImage example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html) from the documentation. The problem is that these custom UI behaviors that derive from Graphic can't be masked by a [Mask component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Mask.html), even though every native UI element can be. This is very strange because according to the [`Graphic.OnPopulateMesh`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.OnPopulateMesh.html) documentation, `Text`, `Image`, and `RawImage` all use this same method.

To reproduce:

1. Create a UI Canvas.
2. Create a UI Image named Mask as a child of the UI Canvas.
3. Add a Mask component to the Mask game object.
4. Add an Image and a SimpleImage as children of Mask.
5. Observe that the Image is masked while the SimpleImage is not.

This is a problem for me because I need to use custom graphics in Scroll Views. What can I do to make my graphics maskable the same as Unity's graphics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured this out right as I finished typing it. It's ridiculously easy. All you have to do is inherit from [`MaskableGraphic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.MaskableGraphic.html) instead of `Graphic`.

Comment: That makes sense. I poked around a bit at the documentation yesterday when I saw your question and couldn't figure it out. There's nothing about the Mask class that says that the graphic needs to be of a certain type (i.e. MaskableGraphic)!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Makes me feel less dumb for not realizing this sooner.